# Custom date format in Linqpad

Tags: linqpad

I would like LinqPad to render some DateTime column with only date format, no time part.

I tried to use data annotation attributes (like in ASP.NET MVC) for my entities:

```
public class MyEntity
{
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime ActivationDate { get; set; }
}
```

but it seems like LinqPad does not recognize it.

Any ideas how to apply custom formatting in LinqPad output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now, there are two options. The first is to do it globally: go to Edit | Preferences > Results, and enter the desired DateTime format string. The other is via a custom projection:

```
from m in MyEntities
select new
{
   ActivationDate = m.ActivationDate.ToString ("....custom string....."),
   ...
}
```

It's an interesting question as to whether LINQPad should read and honor the DisplayFormatAttribute in rendering DateTimes. I'll look into this tomorrow and post back.

Comment: Interesting indeed. The same could be said for `DebuggerDisplayAttribute`.

Comment: Joe, thank you for response (and great product of course). I believe ASP.NET community will really appreciate if LinqPad honor data annotation attributes so we can easily share exact same queries between the code and LinqPad.

Comment: The danger if LINQPad started honoring DisplayFormatAttribute is that exports to Excel might fail because of ambiguous DateTime formatting. Also, you might want to see more detail in LINQPad that you display to the user. There would need to be an obvious way to switch off this behavior, which makes the feature complicated...